# Is it possible to overwrite "abstract" react-native-web code with "imperative" react.js code?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a question about the react-native-for-web library. I am asking whether it is possible to inject plain react.js code to overwrite what would be automatically created by `react-native-web`.

I am consiering using react-native-for-web **ONLY**, **INSTEAD** of using react.js, since I now wanna have a mobile app too. An example react.js code that I am concerned that it would not be achievable with `react-native-web` would would be this code:

```
  <div 
    className="cursor-pointer flex flex-col justify-center items-center"
    onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
    onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
    onMouseLeave={this.onMouseOut}
    onTouchStart={this.onTouchStart}
    onTouchEnd={this.onTouchEnd}
    onTouchCancel={this.onTouchCancel}
    onTouchMove={this.onTouchMove}
  >
    {/* Content here */}
  </div>
```

As you can see the code is pretty web-specific, the event handlers. Or maybe I would also be using some very specific offline-map-library and would want to do one whole component that differentiates it usage on the web from its usage on native, so for one specific component, write it with react.js once and then with react-native the other time, separately, but for all other code only use `react-native-web`.

Another example use case for this scenario, to understand my general question:

I would want to use `react-native-skia` with `Rive` on Native iOS/Android. But then of course skia does not run on web, so how could I make `react-native-web` use the `React.js` web-version of `Rive` instead, when on the web? I am thinking that this might seem like I should maybe instead of `react-native-web` be using a monorepo where I share the core of my react.js/react-native and but I cannot answer this for sure, since I do not know whether this abstract-overwrite is maybe possible anyways, in `react-native-web`.

Is such differentiation possible with `react-native-web`?

Note:
I do not have much experience with react-native or react.js, just the fundamentals.

related questions:

[Can react js web code be used for building mobile apps using react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134839/can-react-js-web-code-be-used-for-building-mobile-apps-using-react-native)

[Can I develop web application using React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68950883/can-i-develop-web-application-using-react-native)

[React Native + React (for web) seed project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591233/react-native-react-for-web-seed-project?rq=2)
(I am asking about not splitting the UI, but about overwriting only part of it in web/native)